# Template apps for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there a good place to get starter apps for iPhone, where you choose from any of a large set of permutations?...for instance with a nav bar and a flip screen and a 3 deep table view, with Core Data support etc.  I guess what I was hoping for is some kind of wizard where you can check a few boxes and have a working app as a starting point....but more than just the 3 or 4 choices that come with xCode.  If not a wizard, just a nice set of a couple dozen permutations.

Also....is there any good sample apps out there that show the difference between identical apps, one which uses Interface Builder and one not?

Aside from being handy for myself, I'd think these would be great as a teaching tool.  I've googled a bit and come up with nothing.

Comment: Why don't you just write the code yourself? You'll learn a lot more from that than from copy-pasting generated code... If you want to be taught stuff, buy a book.

Comment: I prefer learning by example, as I find it most time efficient, especially since I don't really know if the way I am doing things is the way a more experienced person would do it.  If buying a book and then just doing routine tasks yourself is your favorite means of learning, more power to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.appsamuck.com/ may not be all you want but is a good place for you to start.

Comment: Not seen that before. Certainly worth a look!

Comment: Thanks, although I am familiar with this site and was hoping for more generic templates (like the 3 or 4 that come with xCode), I'm assuming there is no such thing out there now, so you won the coin toss for getting your answer accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com : each part of the SDK has numerous examples, although the focus is on the parts of the SKD they represent, you will find pretty good overall coverage.